# how to align a textview to the right of imageview

Tags: android, xml

I'm a beginner in android development and this is my code (it's relative layout)

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/telephone1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/text4"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="00966-13-8420444"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/logo1"
    />
```

I thought android:layout_toRightOf="@id/logo1 is enough
and the text was on the right of the image (aligned correctly) but it appears on the top of device (the place of image on the bottom but not on bottom edge), what line of code I should add?

sorry for English.
thank you

Comment: Your text is actually aligned to right of your image , only with 0 margin .Try layout_marginLeft and layout_marginTop for textview .

Comment: post a fuller xml layout (you are missing the parent tag)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want your text outside the picture, but aligned to its center, try this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/telephone1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/text4"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="00966-13-8420444"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/logo1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you @leonz. Your solution gave me a hint, but it needs some modifications. I assume you probably mean that both ImageView and LinearLayout are in RelativeLayout, and then you add android:layout_toRightOf="@id/logo1" to LinearLayout instead of the TextView

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your questions clearly, You want to display image and textview in a single row. Also, Your textview is right side of imageView. If it is so. Please copy/paste below. It should work

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="00966-13-8420444"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Layout Structure like this and then Move around the `LinearLayout` wherever you like using `android:gravity`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="Horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/telephone1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="00966-13-8420444"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/telephone1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/text4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="00966-13-8420444"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/logo1"

/>
```